# how to keep alive Angular 4 app?

Tags: angular, api, session, single-sign-on, keep-alive

In Angular 4 application button clicks are not working if the user is idle for sometimes. The user has to reload entire application to make it work again. How to keep it alive?

I have simple code.

my.component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="click_func(value)">demo</button>
```

my.component.ts

```
click_func(param1:string){
    this._apiService.myapi(param1)
        .subscribe(res=>{if(res){this.somedata=res}})
}
```

myservice.service.ts

```
myapi(param1:string):Observable<any>{
    return this._http.get(this.apiurl+'/'+param1)
            .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
}
```

The API is written in Django.
I am using SSO on the server to authenticate.
On being idle for sometimes and then calling any API ,I am seeing no data in the response and I see SMSESSION as **LOGGEDOFF** in response cookie.
Any solution?

Comment: end of the day angular application is just HTML and Javascript in your browser, that will keep alive for long time. There is not session timeout for a angular application.
You can check for possibilities for having any other issues like API you are caling or any cache services you are using.

Comment: Check for error messages while calling API in browser console and network tabs.

Comment: We has similar problem in our app but only in webview content like Windows/Andorid app. It was connected with system settings. I doesn't understand you problem. Maybe it's connected with sso ticket alive?

Comment: @Sreekumar you are correct. There isn't any problem with the application. I see SMSESSION as *LOGGEDOFF* when I get the response from the server. Any solution for this?

Comment: might help you: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+Configure+Single+Sign+On+Session+Timeout